# Matching More than One ParserResult and Extracting Values

Tags: f#, fparsec

This is a question about working with FParsec's ParserResult.

Is there a cleaner implementation of `match_result` to pull out the `XKEYVALUE` or `XATTRIBUTES` contained inside the `ParserResult` without two nested matches?

The following code works as a F# console app...

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

open System
open FParsec

// Types
type XKEYVALUE = string * string
type XATTRIBUTES = Map< string, string>

type PARSER_RESULT_XML = 
    | PR_XKEYVALUE of ParserResult<XKEYVALUE, unit>
    | PR_XATTRIBUTES of ParserResult<XATTRIBUTES, unit>

// Parser Trace
let (<!>) (p: Parser<_,_>) label : Parser<_,_> =
    fun stream ->
        printfn "%A: Entering %s" stream.Position label
        let reply = p stream
        do
            match (reply.Status) with
                | Ok  -> printfn "%A: Leaving %s (%A) - %A" stream.Position label reply.Status reply.Result
                | Error -> printfn "%A: Leaving %s (%A) - %A" stream.Position label reply.Status reply.Error
                | FatalError -> printfn "%A: Leaving %s with FatalError (%A)" stream.Position label reply.Status
                | _ -> printfn "%A: Leaving %s with unknown status" stream.Position label
        reply

// Parsers
let ws = spaces
let str = pstring
let xKey : Parser<string,unit> = (ws >>. regex "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9:]*") <!> "xKey"
let xStringLiteral = regex "[^\"]+" <!> "xStringLiteral"
let xKeyValue : Parser<XKEYVALUE, unit> = 
    ws >>. xKey .>>. (ws >>. str "=" >>. ws >>. str "\"" >>. xStringLiteral .>> str "\"" .>> ws) |>> XKEYVALUE <!> "xKeyValue"
let xAttributes : Parser<XATTRIBUTES, unit> = sepEndBy xKeyValue ws |>> XATTRIBUTES <!> "xAttributes"

// Test Data
let xKeyValue_text = """    key =  "value"    aa"""
let xAttributes_text = "key1=\"value1\" key2=\"value2\""

let match_result ( result : PARSER_RESULT_XML) : string =
    match result with 
        | PR_XKEYVALUE(a) ->    match a with  
                                    | Success( ((key : string), (value : string)), x2, x3) -> sprintf "%s=\"%s\"" key value
                                    | Failure( _, _, _) -> sprintf "FAILURE"
        | PR_XATTRIBUTES( a) -> match a with
                                    | Success( (x1 : Map<string, string>), x2, x3) -> sprintf "x1=%A, x2=%A, x3=%A" x1 x2 x3
                                    | Failure( _, _, _) -> sprintf "FAILURE"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    run xKeyValue xKeyValue_text |> PR_XKEYVALUE |> match_result |> printfn "%A"
    run xAttributes xAttributes_text |> PR_XATTRIBUTES |> match_result |> printfn "%A"
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

But `match_result` just seems clumsy with its nested matches.

A failed experiment was to use an [AND pattern match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) to put the match of `PARSER_RESULT_XML & Success( …)` in the same match expression but I couldn't get the types of the two match expressions to agree.

How would you modify `match_result` to do this better or cleaner?

Comment: The code does not compile.

Comment: The code does compile and run, with warnings in in Visual Studio Pro, Version 16.8.2 with default settings.  The VS Pro compiler throws three warnings: 2 x "Incomplete pattern matches on this expression ..." for lines 40 and 43, and 1 x "This rule will never be reached." for line 46.  

Clearly, your compiler is configured to not compile given these warnings.

I have removed the warnings and replaced the code.  Thanks for your comment so I could make this easier for others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pattern match how deep as you need into a structure:

```
let match_result result =
    match result with
    | PR_XKEYVALUE (Success ((key, value), _, _)) -> sprintf "%s=\"%s\"" key value 
    | PR_XATTRIBUTES (Success (x1, x2, x3)) -> sprintf "x1=%A, x2=%A, x3=%A" x1 x2 x3
    | _ -> "FAILURE"
```

Comment: Originally, I tried this but as I am learning F# I might have gotten confused by another error which I thought was due to my attempted deep pattern match.  Thank you for showing me that is DOES work.  Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

This is subjective on my part, but if you get rid of unneeded type annotations and change the indentation on match_result, I think it improves the readability a little bit.

```
let match_result result =
    match result with 
    | PR_XKEYVALUE a ->
        match a with  
        | Success ((key, value), _, _) -> sprintf "%s=\"%s\"" key value
        | Failure _ -> sprintf "FAILURE"
    | PR_XATTRIBUTES a -> 
        match a with
        | Success (x1, x2, x3) -> sprintf "x1=%A, x2=%A, x3=%A" x1 x2 x3
        | Failure _ -> sprintf "FAILURE"
```

If you're still not happy with that, you might find using an active pattern here helpful:

```
let (|KeyValue|Attributes|Failed|) result =
    match result with
    | PR_XKEYVALUE a ->
        match a with  
        | Success ((key, value), _, _) -> KeyValue (key, value)
        | Failure _ -> Failed
    | PR_XATTRIBUTES a -> 
        match a with
        | Success (x1, x2, x3) -> Attributes (x1, x2, x3)
        | Failure _ -> Failed

let match_result result =
    match result with 
    | KeyValue (key, value) -> sprintf "%s=\"%s\"" key value
    | Attributes (x1, x2, x3) -> sprintf "x1=%A, x2=%A, x3=%A" x1 x2 x3
    | Failed -> sprintf "FAILURE"
```

The latter is better in that you're separating out interpreting the result in domain terms, and what to do with it (print messages, in this case).

Comment: Thank you Jim.  I like your use of active patterns to avoid the need to use type constructors.